# error :Undefined property: PostsController::$post

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am having a problem here I am trying to implement full text searching functionality in my application

here is the controller class

```
<?php

class PostsController extends BaseController {

    public function postSearch(){
        $q = Input::get('query');

        $posts = $this->post->whereRaw("MATCH(instance_id,instance_type,availability_zone, status_checks,alarm_status, public_dns, key_name ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", 
            array($q))->get();

        return View::make('ec2_instance.search', compact('ec2_instance'));

    }
}
?>
```

I just cannot see what is wrong any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You do `$this->post` but there is no member variable in your controller called `post`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to implement full text searching on a mysql database in Laravel following this tutorial here : [http://creative-punch.net/2013/12/implementing-laravel-4-full-text-search] , the table I am trying to search is ec2_instance, as you can see the tutorial uses post as opposed to get.

Comment: maybe they injected the model into the constructor in the tutorial ?

Comment: @lagbox They probably did but without a link that's hard to tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wronging in query

```
$posts = $this->post->whereRaw(
    "MATCH(instance_id,instance_type,availability_zone, status_checks,alarm_status, public_dns, key_name ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", 
    array($q)
)->get();
```

Should be

```
$posts = Post::whereRaw(
        "MATCH(instance_id,instance_type,availability_zone, status_checks,alarm_status, public_dns, key_name ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", 
        array($q)
    )->get();
```

The difference is  `$this->post->` to `post::`